# How does If Else statement in JS replace a <div> with another <div> using a <select> dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, innerhtml

```js
// if selectLang.value is spanish display: spanish-lyrics

const selectLang = document.querySelector("select");
const spanishLyrics = document.getElementById("spanish-lyrics");
let lyricText = document.getElementsByClassName("lyric-text");

selectLang.addEventListener("change", setLang);

function setLang(){
  const choice = selectLang.value;
  if (choice === "spanish"){
    lyricText.innerHTML = spanishLyrics.innerHTML;
    console.log("changed");
  } else {
    console.log("not changed");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lang-title">
  <select>
    <option value="english">English</option>
    <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="lyric-text">
  <p class="verse">
    [VERSE 1]
  </p>
</div>

<div id="spanish-lyrics">
  <p class="verse">
    [VERSO 1]
  </p>
</div>
```

Attempted displaying results using `console.log()` and the console displays the `<select>` was changed but the change does not occur on the the webpage.

Comment: `lyricText` is a collection so either use a loop to access each individual item or use `lyricText[0].innerHTML` to target only the first one.